# find and verify contents in subfolders

Tags: bash

I have a directory that contains subdirectores each containing a particular script and supporting files. I need to verify that the proper files are in place in each of these directories. These directories can change at any time, so I'd like to use bash (I think) and store the following command which returns proper subdirectores in an array

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name home -not -name lhome -print
```

and then verify that each of those directories contains the proper files:

`file1 file2 file3.sh file4.conf`

If it a particular directory does not contain those files, I need to know which directory is the issue and which files are missing. What is the best/proper way to achieve that goal? Maybe bash is the wrong tool and perl or something would be better?

Comment: Bash can work but I would use python or perl in that case. Do you only need to print results to console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a more integrated way, but here's my shot at it :

```
while read -rd '' directory; do
    files=("file1" "file2" "$directory.sh" "$directory.conf")
    for file in "${files[@]}"; do
        if [ ! -e "$directory/$file" ]; then
            echo "$directory is missing $file"
        fi
    done
done <  <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name home -not -name lhome -print0)
```

Note that this `find` also returns the current directory. If you wish to avoid that, you might want to add a `-mindepth 1` option.

Also to make it into a script, you might want to replace the `find` kocation `.` by `$1` so you can specify the target more flexibly.

Comment: Nice :) My suggestion would be to use `-print0` with find and `-d ''` with `read` to deal with non-standard directory names

Comment: What if, say...I'm a moron...and forgot that file3.sh and file4.conf are named the same as their directory?  How would I get that variable to come before it does as you have it?

Comment: then define FILES in the first-level loop and use the existing `$directory` variable, e.g. `FILES="file1 file2 $directory.sh $directory.conf"`

Comment: @sjsam thanks, I edited my answer to include your suggestions

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a small part of a much bigger "problem" and I now have a great place to start. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might work:

```
shopt -s nullglob extglob
diff <(while IFS= read -r f; do printf "%s\n" "$f/"{file1,file2,file3.sh,file4.conf}; done < <(printf "%s\n" !(home|lhome))) \
     <(printf "%s\n" !(home|lhome)/{file1,file2,file3.sh,file4.conf})
```

Basically what is happening is that a list of all possible files is generated by the while loop, something like:

```
c/file1
c/file2
c/file3.sh
c/file4.conf
d/file1
d/file2
d/file3.sh
d/file4.conf
```

Then another list is generated with the existing files:

```
c/file1
c/file2
```

Now all that is missing is to compare the two lists to find the differences:

```
2,5d1
< c/file2
< c/file3.sh
< c/file4.conf
< d/file1
7,8d2
< d/file3.sh
< d/file4.conf
```

As you can see this have some serious drawbacks, for one the list of expected files is written twice. And each list is stored in memory which would cause problems if many directories is present.